# Gutenberg dependencies in package.json

Tags: javascript, block-editor

Seeing as `@wordpress/scripts` will magic my development versions of `@wordpress/*` dependencies, should any of them be present in the `package.json` for my own block development?

Gutenberg examples [package.json](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/blob/master/01-basic-esnext/package.json) refers exclusively to `@wordpress/scripts` despite [the entrypoint file](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/blob/master/01-basic-esnext/src/index.js) referring to `@wordpress/i18n` and `@wordpress/blocks`. Should I do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, it depends...

The WP Scripts package depends on the `@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin` package at:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin

What this will do is search for packages from `@wordpress` and list them in a file to make it easy for you to load the list of dependencies when enqueuing. It also adjusts webpack so that it knows not to compile in those dependencies, but instead rely on WordPress to provide them at runtime via enqueuing. As a result, the packages aren't needed, and you don't end up with 20 copies of `@wordpress/element` loaded on the page from every extra block installed.

So, you don't need to put `@wordpress/element` in your `package.json` requirements when using wp scripts to build the assets. This only applies to WordPress packages though. Other libraries on the other hand get included the normal way.

Comment: following your link, i notice it also extracts references to jquery, lodash, moment and react.